# Importing CSV Files in Rails => add certain fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I followed [this tutorial](https://richonrails.com/articles/importing-csv-files) to import a csv file. The tutorial explains how to exclude certain fields:

```
Player.create!(player_hash.except("number"))
```

Is it possible to add certain fields when creating a new player from the cvs? For example: create a new player by getting the name from the cvs file and add the team_id that is not in the csv file. Something like this:

```
Player.create!(player_hash.add("team_id"))
```

But this throws an error:

> undefined method 'add'

Is there a way to add a field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are looking for is `.merge(another_hash)`. So you should do something like:

```
Player.create!(player_hash.except("number").merge({ team_id: some_id }))
```